# Internal thinning

Tags: opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

Given the outcome of applying a canny edge detector into an image using cv2 python library, I want to dilate the edges only from the internal part of the convex boundaries by using morphological operators. What kind of structure element should I use for that?

Comment: Morphological closing of canny edges to segment object contours has been addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757108/python-opencv-fill-contours-which-are-not-completely-closed)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but here is a simple trick:

- You duplicate you image
- You put to 0 everything outside the convex boundaries, like that only the inner pixels will be used during the dilation
- You apply the dilation
- You compute the maximum between the original image and the dilation result.

You can use the structuring element of your choice. Square is often a little bit aggressive, when a ball preserve the euclidean distance.