# python opencv fill contours which are not completely closed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I use openCV to find the external contour of a given image and fill it.
The images I use as input are images of pants like the one attached. The problem is that sometimes (like in the attached image) the contour is not completely closed and then I can't fill it. What can I do in this case?
Please see code below.

Thanks, Li

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy
import bs4
import scipy
import cv2

image_obj_original = cv2.imread(image_file)
image_name = os.path.split(image_file)[-1]
name, extension = os.path.splitext(image_name)

# normalize to a standard size
image_obj = cv2.resize(image_obj_original, STANDARD_SIZE)

imWithBorder = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image_obj, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[255, 255, 255])
# convert to grey-scale
greyscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(imWithBorder,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# get canny edges
canny_edges = cv2.Canny(greyscale_image, 1, 255)

h, w = canny_edges.shape[:2]
contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( canny_edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours = [cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 3, True) for cnt in contours0]
vis = numpy.zeros((h, w, 3), numpy.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(vis,contours,0,255,-1)
vis = cv2.bitwise_not(vis)
cv2.imshow('image', vis)
```

Comment: Where's the attached image?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is somewhat annoying that Canny in OpenCV is not always closing one last pixel in contour of object, and that prevent you from finding one closed contour. The workaround that I used to solve this problem is use of "close" morphological operation:

```
dilate(canny_edges, canny_edges, Mat());
erode(canny_edges, canny_edges, Mat());
```

As any workaround it is not perfect but it does solves the problem.